# Unable to start DSE service with IPV6 address configured

Tags: cassandra, dse

```
[root@r7515-114-vm19 ~]# service dse stop;service dse start
Stopping DSE daemon : dse
dse is already stopped
Starting DSE daemon : dse
DSE daemon starting with only Cassandra enabled (edit /etc/default/dse to enable other features)
WARNING: Timed out while waiting for DSE to start. The service may have started though. Please check your logs.


ERROR [main] 2022-11-02 15:18:47,393  DseModule.java:108 - Exiting...
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) An exception was caught and reported. Message: Configured listen_interface "ens192" could not be found
  at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.configure(Unknown Source)

1 error
        at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:466)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:155)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
        at com.datastax.bdp.ioc.DseInjector.get(DseInjector.java:36)
        at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:102)
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Configured listen_interface "ens192" could not be found
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.getNetworkInterfaceAddress(DatabaseDescriptor.java:533)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applyAddressConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1469)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applyAddressConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1327)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applyAll(DatabaseDescriptor.java:574)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.daemonInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:233)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.daemonInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:254)
        at com.datastax.bdp.DseCoreModule.<init>(DseCoreModule.java:83)
        at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.getRequiredModules(DseModule.java:161)
        at com.datastax.bdp.server.AbstractDseModule.configure(AbstractDseModule.java:27)
        at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.configure(DseModule.java:88)
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:110)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:138)
```

**Also getting below exceptions while trying with listen_address instead of listen_interface.**

```
ERROR [DSE main thread] 2022-11-02 17:11:00,115  CassandraDaemon.java:938 - Exception encountered during startup
java.net.SocketException: Protocol family unavailable
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:461)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:453)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:222)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:130)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:580)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1332)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:488)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:473)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:984)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:276)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:366)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:495)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Getting above exception while starting DSE service with IPV6 address configured on nodes and I didn't see any issue from network setting and interface side.

any workaround for above issue??

Comment: This is a better question for https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassandra as this is a DBA/admin ops category. Also, there is no information as to what is the DSE version (`dse -v` command would print it) here for debugging. `Configured listen_interface "ens192" could not be found` warrants a triage to make sure the networking is done right and is accessible from the DSE node/machine.

Comment: https://support.datastax.com/s/article/Malformed-IPv6-address-at-index-7-when-running-nodetool-and-dsetool maybe of help after you figure out the networking to the `ens192` interface.